# How to change the mouse cursor theme?

Tags: themes

I would like to change the mouse cursor theme that is used, both in my session and in the login screen.

For example [Breeze](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Breeze?content=165371) instead of the standard one called "elementary" (similar to DMZ Black).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The following answer uses `Breeze` as an example, don't forget it to replace it with the name of the theme you actually want to install.*

## For all users

To install an icon theme download it and move the theme directory (containing a file called `index.theme` or `cursor.theme`) to `/usr/share/icons/`.

Open a Terminal. First put the name of the cursor theme you want to install into the variable `THEMENAME`. Then set `FILENAME` to either `index.theme` or `cursor.theme` depending on the filename in the theme directory.

```
THEMENAME=Breeze
FILENAME=index.theme
```

You should make sure that permissions are correct after copying the theme, so run `chown -hR root:root /usr/share/icons/"$THEMENAME"` ([chown](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man3/chown) changes the owner of a files / directories) and `chmod -R 755 /usr/share/icons/"$THEMENAME"` ([chmod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/chmod) changes permissions to read, write and execute).

Change the used theme by entering the following in Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme "$THEMENAME"

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/"$THEMENAME"/"$FILENAME" 21

sudo update-alternatives --set x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/"$THEMENAME"/"$FILENAME"
```

You probably need to reboot for all changes to take effect.

## Only for current user

To install an icon theme download it and move the theme directory (containing a file called `index.theme` or `cursor.theme`) to `~/.icons/`.

Open a Terminal and put the name of the cursor theme you want to install into the variable `THEMENAME`:

```
THEMENAME=Breeze
```

Change the used theme by entering the following in Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme "$THEMENAME"
```

## Related known bugs

[(Pantheon) Files currently has a bug where a custom cursor theme is not properly applied.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1395935)

Comment: Note: For me my answer does not work in login screen and the cursor is also reset to some weird default (older, not elementary) when I log out and log back in again. Maybe someone can improve my answer?

Comment: quassy,  perhaps 'chmod -R 755 <theme_dir>'?

Comment: Was about to add that permissions should be correct after copying the theme to `/usr/share/icons/`, but I did that already (`chmod -R 755 ./Breeze`). Including `chown -hR root:root ./Breeze`.

Comment: could you be more spesific where is that ~/.icons/ directory is??

Comment: @HagridGendut `~` indicates that the directory is in your home folder, typing `~/.icons/` into files will take you straight there. That directory may not exist.