# Change Options from the Terminal

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-terminal

Is it possible to change the options of the Terminal without installing the elementary-tweaks tool?!
I want to change the transparency to 90%, the theme to "Chalk" and the Cursor shape to I-Beam.

Comment: I'd humbly add an [article on ubuntubuzz that explains how to set the darker theme](https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2019/06/enable-dark-theme-on-elementary-os.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change the transparency in Terminal you can use gsettings like this:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings opacity 90`

If you are not happy with the result, you can always change it to a different value or reset it to the default like this:

`gsettings reset org.pantheon.terminal.settings opacity`

To change the cursor shape, you can execute the following:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings cursor-shape I-Beam`

Or to find out what other options are supported:

`gsettings range org.pantheon.terminal.settings cursor-shape`

When you use gsettings to set these options, the changes are applied immediately.

You can change the various colors that are used in Terminal with the palette option, have a look at this setting:

`gsettings get org.pantheon.terminal.settings palette`

An alternative to using gsettings for changing these settings is the graphical user interface tool dconf-editor.
In elementary OS, dconf-editor is not installed by default however.
So, if you want to use this method, you may have to install the package using either *Software Center* or by running this in Terminal:

`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

Start dconf-editor and go to:

`org > pantheon > terminal > settings`

Here you can set the transparency using the *opacity* option or change the cursor shape by selecting a different value for *cursor-shape*.

Comment: In Loki, the `opacity` key isn't there anymore. The default value is `'rgba(37, 46, 50, 0.95)'` -- you can change the opacity (alpha) with the last value.

Comment: the path is now `io.elementary.terminal.settings` and you can change the opacity as stated above by @mqsoh.  However, if the window is fullscreened, it will be 100% opaque no matter what value you give it.

Answer (score 0):

Command to change the Gtk theme (note that I'm using Numix as an example):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Numix"
```

Command to change the icon theme:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "Numix"
```

Command to change the metacity theme:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Numix"
```

As for the cursor theme, [here's a relevant question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/892/how-to-change-the-mouse-cursor-theme).

I don't quite understand what kind of transparency are you trying to set.

Comment: I don't want to change the theme of the desktop. I want to change the theme and transparency of the terminal. Also the Cursor Shape....