# mouse cursor reset to a weird old cursor

Tags: settings, themes

i changed my cursor to breeze a while ago and now i wanted to change to another cursor theme again but i couldnt make it.instead my cursor changed to an old weird theme.now i cant go back to breeze either.
[How to change the mouse cursor theme?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/892/how-to-change-the-mouse-cursor-theme)
i installed the theme with this guide
how can i go back to elementary OS stock?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the steps in the thread you linked, the following commands can revert to the default cursor theme by changing the themename.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme elementary

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/elementary/cursor.theme 21

sudo update-alternatives --set x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/elementary/cursor.theme
```

These three commands will revert these changes. You may need to reboot for these changes to take effect.